# Android - Seekbar problem, unable to change value

Tags: android

Any help with this? I have an error when I try to use the seekbar to change my paint brush width.
The error line is UNDER setStrokeWidth, saying  "Is not applicable for the arguments (string)"

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawing_activity);




    setCurrentPaint();
    currentBrush = new PenBrush();

    drawingSurface = (DrawingSurface) findViewById(R.id.drawingSurface);
    drawingSurface.setOnTouchListener(this);
    drawingSurface.previewPath = new DrawingPath();
    drawingSurface.previewPath.path = new Path();
    drawingSurface.previewPath.paint = getPreviewPaint();


    redoBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.redoBtn);
    undoBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.undoBtn);

    redoBtn.setEnabled(false);
    undoBtn.setEnabled(false);


    //SEEKBAR THICKNESS CHANGE
    //
    //
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekValue);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
            seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            **currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(String.valueOf(progress));**
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

        }
    });
    }
//END SEEKBAR THICKNESS



private void setCurrentPaint(){
    currentPaint = new Paint();
    currentPaint.setDither(true);
    currentPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

}

private Paint getPreviewPaint(){
    final Paint previewPaint = new Paint();
    previewPaint.setColor(0xFFC1C1C1);
    previewPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    previewPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    previewPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    previewPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    return previewPaint;
}




public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        drawingSurface.isDrawing = true;

        currentDrawingPath = new DrawingPath();
        currentDrawingPath.paint = currentPaint;
        currentDrawingPath.path = new Path();
        currentBrush.mouseDown(currentDrawingPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
        currentBrush.mouseDown(drawingSurface.previewPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());


    }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        drawingSurface.isDrawing = true;
        currentBrush.mouseMove( currentDrawingPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY() );
        currentBrush.mouseMove(drawingSurface.previewPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());


    }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){


        currentBrush.mouseUp(drawingSurface.previewPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
        drawingSurface.previewPath.path = new Path();
        drawingSurface.addDrawingPath(currentDrawingPath);

        currentBrush.mouseUp( currentDrawingPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY() );

        undoBtn.setEnabled(true);
        redoBtn.setEnabled(false);

    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setStrokeWidth` takes a `float` parameter, not a `String`. Use `currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(progress);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(String.valueOf(progress)); with:

```
currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(progress);
```

You are trying to pass a string to setStrokeWidth thats why you get the error. Hope that helps. Good Luck!